# PHP Compatibiility Issue

Tags: php, internet-explorer

I need some help with my code.

I am creating a registration form with php.
It's working great in Firefox and Chrome, however in IE it always returns error 400.

but when I look in my database all data are inserted perfectly as well as it sends the confirmation email successfully.

I do not know if the redirect function I used is the one giving the error.

here's the link for my codes:

registration form:
http://pastebin.com/Jv1MHv5Y

reg.php file:
http://pastebin.com/3arnnS8v

when successfully registered the success confirmation will show up and after 5 seconds it will be redirected to the login page.

thanks

Comment: Do you write your own code or do you use phpmyadmin? If it is you own code please add the code and remove the phpmyadmin tags.

Comment: you have to use `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO INCREMENT=0;` when emptying a table, otherwise it will pick up where it left off. are you sure you didn't delete some rows during testing perhaps?

Comment: yes, i write my own code. it is just the tables do not allow me to exceed 8 rows..

Comment: Make sure that there is no error while executing your code, otherwise auto increment will increase the value and it will never be used again until you reset that. So this might be the problem.